# why can't I get req.user in everyauth?

Tags: node.js, express, everyauth

Hello I have a problem with everyauth: I don't know how to configure and get req.user in routes.

Can anybody help me with how to configure?

If you want to see more code just tell me. Thanks for visit

```
.password
    // .loginWith('email')
    .loginWith('login')
    .getLoginPath('/login')
    .postLoginPath('/login')
    .loginView('login.jade')
    .loginLocals( function (req, res, done) {
      setTimeout( function () {
        done(null, {
          title: 'Async login'
        });
      }, 200);
    })
    .authenticate( function (login, password) {
      var errors = [];
      if (!login) errors.push('Missing login');
      if (!password) errors.push('Missing password');
      if (errors.length) return errors;

      var user = usersByLogin[login];

      if (!user) return ['Login failed'];
      if (user.password !== password) return ['Login failed'];
      return user;
    })
```

redirect code:

```
app.get('/home', function(req,res)
  {
    if(req.session.auth)
      {
        console.log(req.user); //undefined
        res.send('youre logged in');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide everyauth a way of looking up your user object from its id by calling:

```
everyauth.everymodule.findUserById(function(userId, callback) {
    // Look up the user from userId and call callback(err, user)
    ....
});
```

See the Accessing the User section of the [everyauth website](http://everyauth.com/).